# Capture delete key if not focused in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, keydown

I have a web app which plots points with SVG, I want to add the ability to delete a selected point by pressing the <kbd>delete</kbd> key. I can capture <kbd>delete</kbd> keydown (or up) for the entire document and prevent the default event (Chrome's default behavior is to go back a page), however this obviously blocks all delete events so the <kbd>delete</kbd> button no longer works in forms.

Is there a way to set it up so that the <kbd>delete</kbd> key works as intended in forms/inputs but when anywhere else in the app it can be used as a custom delete function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that came into my mind, is to `stopPropagation` on the `input` and `textarea` fields, then the `preventDefault` should not be triggered on the `document`.

JQuery pseudo code:

```
$('input, textarea').keypress(e, function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).keypress(e, function(e){if(delete) e.preventDefault();});
```

Another possiblity is the check the orignal target on the key event of the document.

Event callback:

```
var originalElement = e.srcElement || e.originalTarget;
if(orignalElement.tagName === 'INPUT' or orignalElement.tagName === 'TEXTAREA'){ return; }
// else do your delete key stuff
```

The first line should be obsolete, if you are using jQuery, because it normalized the event for you, and you can use `e.target` to get the `originalTarget`

Answer (score 2):

My prefered approach would be something like this:

```
$(window).keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 46 && $("input:focus, textarea:focus").length == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("delete key pressed!");
  }
});
```

However, I'm not sure if you'll be able to override the back button behaviour - it seems unlikely that Chrome would allow it, given the potential for abuse.